# $P(x) \sim_{ n \rightarrow \infty} x^{n}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

If $P$ is a monic polynomial and $x$ is a real number $>1$.

So $P(x) = x^{n} + a_{n-1} \cdot x^{n-1} +... + a_0$

In this case do we have : $P(x) \sim_{n \rightarrow \infty} x^{n}$ ?

My first instinct was to factorize : $P(x) = x^{n} \cdot (1 + \text{ some fractions})$, and because $ x > 1$ we have : $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} x^{n} \cdot (1 + \text{ some fractions}) = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} x^n$

But I don't know if this is correct...

Comment: What does it mean to consider $n\to\infty$ in this case? If $P$ is a fixed polynomial, its degree $n$ is also fixed. You can't have it fixed and vary at the same time.

Comment: I have edited my answer. It was slightly incorrect earlier, do consider checking it again.

Comment: Perhaps you mean $x\to\infty$ otherwise the question is uninteresting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best way to check is to evaluate the limit $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{P(x)}{x^n}=a$$

If $a=1$, then the sign $\sim$ is used.

In your question, the limit isn't necessarily $1$, instead it may be finitely greater than $1$.It may even not exist at all, depending on the coefficients.

So, according to the given Information, we can't say anything for certain between the asymptotic relation of the polynomial and $x^n$.

Comment: What does it mean to consider $n\to\infty$ in this case? If $P$ is a fixed polynomial, its degree $n$ is also fixed. You can't have it fixed and vary at the same time.

Comment: @Wojo Please read the question again. It means to ask that "Is a polynomial, if of very high degree asymptotically equal to the term of highest degree in $x$, for $x>1$. " And the answer is perfectly correct : It is

Comment: (continued)... Also, P(x) is a fixed polynomial of degree $n$. And $n$ is very large. Simple. That's why we're evaluating limit at $n \to \infty$.

Comment: If you consider the family of polynomials $P_n(x)=x^n+x^{n-1}$, then we have $\frac{P_n(x)}{x^n}=1+\frac{1}{x}$, which is not $1$. If we are not letting $x\to\infty$, the lower order terms have noticeable contribution too.

Comment: @Wojo I got it. I was wrong. I have tried to fixed it in my edit. Does it look OK now?

Comment: If we consider a family like $P_n(x)=x^n+nx^{n-1}$, the limit is infinite...

Comment: @Wojo Now...? ${}{}{}$

Comment: It may also not exist. The bottom line is that we can't say _anything_ about asymptotic relation between $P(x)$ and $x^n$.

Answer (score 2):

If $x>1$ and $0\le i<j$, $ x^i=o(x^j)$, so
for any polynomial of degree $n$ $\;p(x)=a_n x^n+ \text{terms of lower degree}$, we have
$$p(x)=a_n\mkern1mu x^n+o(x^n),\enspace\text{so by definition}\quad p(x)\sim_{x\to\infty}a_n \mkern1mu x^n.$$

Comment: This answers what happens when $x\to\infty$, while the question is about $n\to\infty$ (whatever that means...)

Comment: You're right. I've replaced with a correct justification using the rules of asymptotic analysis. Thanks!